# Require user input when minting nft

Tags: solidity, nft

Is it possible to require a user to input some information while minting their nft? for example If i wanted the person minting to input their first name then the mint happens and the nft contains their first name? is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. Ask the user for the input in a web app
2. generate an image with their name
3. upload it
4. generate metadata file pointing to this image
5. and then mint the NFT passing it the metadata file URI